# Matching physics properties for multiple objects

Tags: mesh, physics

I have about a thousand cubes in my scene that all require the same physics settings. Is there a way to do this without having to change each mesh separately?

I wish I had added the physics first then duplicated but still it would be helpful if there was a way to add settings to multiple meshes at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all the objects you want to apply the physics to, then click on the object that already has the correct settings whilst holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Then navigate to the physics tab and click *Copy from Active*.

[image]

Comment: No problem. Be sure to mark the thread as answered so it doesn't stay in unanswered unnecessarily.

Comment: I have no options to mark as answered only option is add comment